# Running TestFixtures from multiple class files in NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a simple NUnit project in C#.  I have a file TestFixture.cs that successfully runs its four tests.  If I want to add additional tests in a new CS file, how do I do this?  If I simply copy the code from TestFixture.cs into a new TestFixture2.cs and rename the TestFixture classes to TestFixture3 and 4 respectively, they do not execute.  I would think they would automatically run.  Do I need to tell the runner specifically if it is a file other than TestFixture.cs?  Here is my code:

```
namespace NUnitTest1
{
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture3
{
    [Test]
    public void TestTrue()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    // This test fail for example, replace result or delete this test to see all tests pass
    [Test]
    public void TestFault()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture4
{
    [Test]
    public void TestTrue()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }

    // This test fail for example, replace result or delete this test to see all tests pass
    [Test]
    public void TestFault()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
}
```

}

My unit test runs by executing a command line program using the following code:

```
namespace NUnitTest1
{
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] my_args = { Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location };

        int returnCode = NUnit.ConsoleRunner.Runner.Main(my_args);

        if (returnCode != 0)
            Console.Beep();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you post some info on how you run Nunit?

Comment: I added info on how I run Nunit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit will automatically get all types marked with `TestFixture` attribute from test assembly when you load it (it does not matter whether fixtures in one *.cs* file or in separate). Then NUnit will search for methods marked with `Test` or `TestCase` attributes and load them. If NUnit don't see some test, then make sure you loaded latest version of your test assembly.

NOTE: If you are using NUnit test runner, then there is nice setting *Reload when test assembly changes*. With this option turned on NUnit will automatically reload test assembly when you rebuild it in Visual Studio.

[image]

Comment: That seems to be my issue.  I have those attributes set but the second files tests do not get run.  I have added a section on how I am executing the unit tests.